# How do I properly use datatables in Flask with using templates

Tags: html, flask, datatables

I am trying to form a template using datatables. For some reason my datatables is not working properly.

This is my base.html, I put the Jquery at the bottom of the page so that I can reuse the query every single time.

```
  '''

  <head>

  </head>
  <body>

            {% block content %} {% endblock %}
   <script src="static/plugins/datatables-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.js"></script>

    <script>
            $(function () {
                $('#table1').DataTable({
                  "paging": true,
                  "lengthChange": false,
                  "searching": false,
                  "ordering": true,
                  "info": true,
                  "autoWidth": false,
                });
              });
            </script>
  </body>

'''
```

This is where I am planning to use it. for some reason the thead does not output the table as expected.

```
'''
  {% extends "base.html" %} {% block content %}
      <table id="table1">
          <thead> 
             <tr>Company Name</tr>
             <tr>Pre Money Value</tr>
             <tr>Post Money Value</tr>
             <tr>Round Size </tr>
             <tr>Investment Cost </tr>
             <tr>Status </tr>
              </thead>
      </table>

  {% endblock %}

'''
```

Any help will be fully appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataTables expects a fully-formed HTML table, which you're missing.

From DataTables site:

> In order for DataTables to be able to function correctly, the HTML for the target table must be laid out in a well formed manner with the 'thead' and 'tbody' sections declared.

For example:

```html
<table id="table_id">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>etc</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
            <td>etc</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
            <td>etc</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Notably, your table is missing `<tbody>`. It's not clear from your code what you actually intend to have in the body of the table, but you'll also need to ensure your data conforms to the appropriate rows/columns.

I would also suggest using `$(document).ready();`, unless you're tying your function to a button press or something.

Also from the DataTables site:

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried that,
for some reason the thead is not showing
The console has errors but I don't know how to fix it

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined
    at _fnSortFlatten (jquery.dataTables.js:5889)
    at _fnSortingClasses (jquery.dataTables.js:6227)
    at loadedInit (jquery.dataTables.js:1208)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.js:1306)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k.fn.init.DataTable [as dataTable] (jquery.dataTables.js:869)
    at k.fn.init.$.fn.DataTable (jquery.dataTables.js:15161)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (test:318)
    at e (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: Heads up, if you don't respond to the answer I posted, I won't be notified that you posted here. I would troubleshoot loading the script at the top of your page, and using the example table provided by DataTables.net to see if you can get that working as a baseline.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very good article about datatables.net in Flask : her POC works very well. :)

- [Alta Fang, June 1st, 2019:
  Making a web app that updates a database based on table row selections](https://altafang.com/2019/06/01/making-a-web-app-that-updates-a-database-based-on-table-row-selections/)